How to create dynamic altair x-axis and not fixed on current values?
My data looks like this:



Name
Date
1%
2%
10%
...
100%




Anne
1/1/24
3
5
1
...
92


Anne
1/2/24
4
8
2
...
78


Anne
1/3/24
7
9
6
...
47



My x axis are the percentages: 1%, 2%, 5%, 10%, 15%, 25%, 50%, and 100%
I created my table using altair:
import altair as alt

chart_df = newdf.drop(columns = ['NAME'])
chart_df = chart_df.astype({col: 'float' for col in chart_df.columns if col != 'DATE'})

numeric_cols = sorted(chart_df.columns[1:].to_list(), key=float)

chart_df = chart_df[['DATE'] + numeric_cols]

chart_df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(chart_df['DATE'], format='%Y.%m.%d')
chart_df = chart_df.melt(id_vars = ['DATE'], var_name = '%age', value_name = 'Output')

chart_df['DATE'] = chart_df['DATE'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

#st.write('Melted Dataframe:', chart_df)
chart = alt.Chart(chart_df).mark_circle(size = 60).encode(alt.X('%age:O', 
                                                                sort = numeric_cols),
                                                          alt.Y('Output:Q'),
                                                          color='DATE:N',
                                                          tooltip=['DATE:N', '%age:O', 'Output:Q']
                                                         ).properties(width = 600, height = 400)
st.altair_chart(chart, use_container_width = True)

This looks fine, but the x axis values are separated by a fixed distance instead of their actual values separated between the 0-100 range. The values at 1% and 2% should be located a lot closer than the values at 2% and 5%, however they're all separated by the same distance.
Here's what the chart looks like currently:

And here's what it should look like with the values dynamically placed within the 0-100% domain:


If you change the x data type from ordinal “O” to quantitative “Q” does that give you the result you’re looking for?

Unfortunately no, but when I switched to using plotly it worked, so I think it's something with the altair library that doesn't recognize the inputs as numbers

Please provide a complete MWE with data and I can take a look.
